# SQL Query to fetch data by combining 4 tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT ae.c_id, 
            eng.e_id, 
            ab.b_id, 
            a.* 
FROM   account a 
   INNER JOIN acct_c_id_assoc ae 
           ON a.acct_id = ae.acct_id 
   INNER JOIN acct_e_id_assoc eng 
           ON a.acct_id = eng.acct_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN acct_b_id_assoc ab 
                ON a.acct_id = ab.acct_id 
WHERE  a.inactv_sts = 'N' 
   AND ae.inactv_sts = 'N' 
   AND ae.sys_id = 5 
   AND eng.e_id = '101' 
   AND a.acct_id NOT IN (SELECT acct_id 
                         FROM   acct_b_id_assoc) ORDER  BY a.create_dtm DESC
```

There 4 tables:
Account-acct id PK,
Entitiles(E_ID_assoc)-acct id PK&FK,E_ID PK&FK,
Cores(C_ID_assoc)-acct id PK&FK,C_ID PK&FK
Benefits(B_ID_assoc)-acct id PK&FK,B_ID PK&FK

i need to fetch all accounts with unique C_ID(Core id must not be repeated to multiple accounts) with specific entitiles i.e 101 and must have not B_ID associated(no benefits present for the account)

above is the query i have tried, but i am getting accounts with same Core id's

//a.inactv_sts='N' and ae.inactv_sts = 'N' and ae.sys_id=5 this line means account is active is associated with some core id

can anyone help me with this

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT keyword works by getting the distinct values across all selected columns in your query. In your case it will be distinct for (ae.c_id, eng.e_id, ab.b_id, a.*). Not just distinct values of c_id. e.g. if same c_id but say eng.e_id is different it will be in output result.

To explain further lets say table is cities with cols  country and city

```
US      NewYork
US      Boston
France  Paris
Canada  Toronto
Canada  Vancouver

select distinct country from cities  -- will return US, France, Canada

select distinct country, city from cities  -- will return every row.
```

Comment: how can i exclude accounts which have same C_ID in the query?

Comment: there are multiple ways. One way is to just get first C_ID and than pass it to another query and get all the related data.. i.e  Select * from blah where C_ID in ( your distinct query).